# How do I create a loop based on file size in power shell

Tags: powershell, autodesk, intune

I am working with [*intune*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/what-is-intune) and PowerShell and I basically want to run a *exe* file which downloads 15.2GB / 7932 files for the insulation off the [*autodesk*](https://www.autodesk.com/) website and then creates a text file so that *intune* knows that it's done as I want to delete all the install files with another script later.

The problem is the PowerShell script will run and close before it has finished downloading and *intune* thinks it is done and the next script tries to install what was downloaded but it is not fully downloaded so it fails.

I have tried to put a `wait` command but *intune* will just hang and you will have to restart windows which is something I don't want the users to do.

I am thinking to add a loop so ot checks the file size of the following folder:

```
C:\Autodesk\{E658F785-6D4D-4B7F-9BEB-C33C8E0027FA}
```

and once it reaches 15.2GB / 7932 files it goes to the next step and creates the text file.

Below is my current PowerShell script:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "\\arch-syd-fs\EM Setup\Autodesk Recap Custom Install 2023\Source 1 Download\Revit_2023.exe" -ArgumentList "--quiet' " -Wait
New-Item "C:\Temp\Revit 2023" -Type Directory
New-Item -Path "C:\Temp\Revit 2023\Download Done.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break this down into 3 questions

- How do you check the size of a directory?
- How do you check the count of files in a directory?
- How do you make a script wait until these checks reach a certain value?

It turns out you can do the first 2 together

```
$dirStats = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force 'C:\path\to\whatever' | Measure-Object -Sum Length
$size = $dirStats.Sum
$fileCount = $dirStats.Count
```

Then you can wrap it in a do-until loop (with a delay to keep it from eating all the CPU) to make the script wait until those values reach a certan threshold

```
do {
    Start-Sleep 5
    $dirStats = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force 'C:\path\to\whatever' | Measure-Object -Sum Length
    $size = $dirStats.Sum
    $fileCount = $dirStats.Count
} until( ($size -ge 15.2*1024*1024*1024) -and ($fileCount -ge 7932) )
```

Note that `$size` is in bytes, and you might want to make that an `-or` condition rather than an `-and` depending on weather you want the script to return after either condition is met or wait for both.

Comment: thanks that worked  here is the script that worked

Comment: Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath  "C:\Temp\Recap 2023\ReCapPro_2023.exe"

do {
    Start-Sleep 5
    $dirStats = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force 'C:\Autodesk\{3A3F0063-7E03-4026-BD00-5E517E2F13CA}' | Measure-Object -Sum Length
    $size = $dirStats.Sum
    $fileCount = $dirStats.Count
} until( ($size -ge 4.63*1024*1024*1024) -and ($fileCount -ge 243) )

New-Item "C:\Temp\Recap 2023" -Type Directory
New-Item -Path "C:\Temp\Recap 2023\Download Done.txt"

Comment: @brendansmith If my answer solved your problem, please consider clicking the check mark to "accept this answer"